# How to read any kind of files as binary and edit it as you want (like compress it) with c++?

Tags: c++, binary, compression, fstream

I'm trying to figure out a way to manipulate the binary code of any file in the computer in goal to apply a compress/decompress algorithm in c++ .
I have been searching about that for long time and all i found was how to read a .bin file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
streampos size;
char * memblock;

ifstream file ("name.bin", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
if (file.is_open())
{
size = file.tellg();
memblock = new char[size];
file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
file.read (memblock, size);

for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){

    cout << memblock[i] ;

}

file.close();

cout << "\n\n the entire file content is in memory";

delete[] memblock;
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
return 0;

}
```

I just wanna those bytes without ASCII translation, other words i wanna all the file as binary not what is inside it

Comment: it looks like that is what you already have. You are already reading in binary. Any problem you have is trying to print the output to your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simpler than we thought :

## include bitset

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){

//changing the value of "memblock[i]" to binary byte per byte with for loop
//and of course using bitset

bitset<8> test (memblock[i]);
cout << test ;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is overloaded for `char` types to output the ASCII formated character. The data (the ones and zeros) in your `memblock` array are accurately read in as binary. It's just the way you're displaying them that is ASCII. Instead of a `char[]` for `memblock`, make it a `uint8_t[]`. Then, when you output, do

```
std::cout << std::hex << std::fill('0') << std::setw(2) << memblock[i];
             ^           ^                 ^
             |           |                 |
             |           |            sets the width of the next output
             |        sets the fill character (default is space)
          tells the stream to output all numbers in hexadecimal
```

You'll have to `#include <iomanip>` for the stream format manipulators `hex`, `fill`, and `setw` to work.

Note that `setw` will only be set on the stream for the next output operation, while `hex` and `fill` will be set until explicitly set otherwise. That said, you only need to set these two manipulators once, probably outside your loop. Then when you're finished, you can set them back like:

```
std::cout << std::dec << std::fill(' ');
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2 for the list of overloaded `operator<<` functions for `char` and `char` arrays.

Comment: thanks @John but another problem is facing me , it's says i can not put unit8_t structure in the method read() :                                                                                                                      

" invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'std::basic_istream<char>::char_type*' {aka 'char*'} [-fpermissive]| "

that's the code :



  uint8_t * memblock;
  memblock = new uint8_t[size];

Comment: How are you trying to output it?

Comment: cout << hex << memblock[i] ;
but that's not the error that the compiler flag to me

Comment: If that's the case, then my choice of `uint8_t` was a bad one, since apparently that's an alias for `unsigned char`. If that's the case, then get rid of the `uint8_t` and use `unsigned short int`. I've been able to get away with using `uint8_t` in the past but that must have been my particular compiler allowing me to, and something not actually language compliant. Your error message looks like you're trying to convert a `uint8_t*` to a `char*` pointer, though - not a `uint8_t` to a `char`. What line does this error refer to?

Comment: That line : file.read (memblock, size);                                           and it's the same problem with " unsigned short int"

Comment: Okay I see. `ifstream::read` expects the first argument to be a `char *`. I think the solution is to have `memblock` be a `char[]`, and when you output, `std::cout << static_cast<unsigned short>(memblock[i])`.